# Typesetting of symbols and "operators" denoting sets

Tags: soft-question, notation, mathematical-writing

**Question:**

what are the conventions for typesetting sets of certain objects, especially the vertices and edges of a graph or those adjacent to an edge or vertex.

For vectors and matrices there is the convention to use boldface, for operators and functions it is roman. but I could not find any mention of how to typeset various kinds of sets ; does it depend on the context or are there general rules?

Is it a valid conclusion that boldface is used for "composite" objects, and thus also for sets; do "subset selectors" that e.g denote the edges that are adjacent to a vertex count as operators and should thus be typeset in roman?

Comment: I think symbols like $\mathscr F$ are used to denote sets of sets. Symbols like $\mathbb R$ are used to denote certain most important sets of numbers -- which is why I prefer $\mathsf P$ and $\mathsf E$ (or even $P$ and $E$) to $\mathbb P$ and $\mathbb E$ in order to denote the probability and the expectation. I'd suggest something like $A_v$ or $E_v$ for the set of edges adjacent to vertex $v$, and $A^e$ or $V^e$ for the set of vertices adjacent to edge $e$ -- using "simple" Roman letters, since these sets are sets of simple, "atomic" objects.

Comment: Note that boldface was initially used for $\mathbf{R}$, $\mathbf{Z}$ (mathbf = math boldface), and at blackboard was denoted with two lines rather than a thick line: $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{Z}$ (mathbb = math blackboard). Eventually these letters were used in printed form too (in primitive TeX they were artificially produced using backspaces, e.g., $I\!\!R$, $Z\!\!\!Z$)...

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no canonical convention for typesetting the kind of objects mentioned in the question. Mostly, $V$ for the vertex set, $E$ for edge set of a graph, and $\delta(v)$ for the set of edges adjacent to vertex $v$ is used. Sometimes one writes $\delta_G(v)$ where $G$ is the underlying graph. This can be useful if one wishes to distinguish several graphs.

I prefer the notations used by [Douglas West](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Ewest/grammar.html). He points out that a *graph is not as set* and suggests to use $V(G)$ and $E(G)$ to denote the vertex set and the edge set of a graph. I would recommend to have a look at the [The Grammar According to West](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Ewest/grammar.html). It is quite comprehensive and might answer your question in detail.

Comment: So does West not work in ZF(C)? /s

Comment: I always thought that $\delta(v)$ denoted the degree of a vertex... I see that it is necessary to define the symbols and notation used which in turn gives some freedom of choosing notation. The linked articles are interesting in their own right

Comment: Yes, some authors also use $\delta(v)$ for the degree of a vertex. I would use $\text{deg}(v)$ in this case, sometimes also $d(v)$ is used...As far as I know it depends on the subfield you are working on which notation is used.